# Dagger migration to Hilt, @ContributesAndroidInjector not working with fragment annotaded with @AndroidEntryPoint

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Trying to migrate screen by screen from `Dagger` to `Hilt`. Migrated one activity and it works fine, but most of app activities use `DialogFraments`, and it is okay when adding annotation `@AndroidEntryPoint` for `DialogFragment`, but then old not migrated activities not working with that fragment, getting runtime error:

```
Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity. Found: class com......MainActivity
```

Any ideas how to make DialogFragment work on Hilt and Dagger activities together?

After annotating `MainActivity` with `@AndroidEntryPoint` getting much more dependancy injection errors, only fix I can see then migrate all activity modules.

Any easier way to make them work together so migration could be done step by step, not whole activity modules?

Answer (score 0):

Saviour ansver is `@OptionalInject` and `OptionalInjectCheck.wasInjectedByHilt(this)` check

The way to do it is replace:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : DaggerAppCompatDialogFragment() {
....
}
```

with

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@OptionalInject
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : AppCompatDialogFragment(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector() = androidInjector


    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
       
        if (!OptionalInjectCheck.wasInjectedByHilt(this)) {
            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
        }

    }
....
}
```

And it is working with new Hilt activities and no changes is needed with old `@ContributesAndroidInjector` pattern with no additional changes!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with BottomSheetDialog and your solution doesn't work, do you have any idea?